# Get records around a birthday

Tags: mysql

I would like to get all records plus/minus 10 years around the user's birthday.

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE cbe_user_birthday - INTERVAL 10 YEARS AND
   cbe_user_birthday + INTERVAL 10 YEARS
```

... but it returns this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'YEARS AND cbe_user_birthday + INTERVAL 10 YEARS'` at line 2

Comment: Next time post your error message, `Doesnt work`  isnt very helpfull. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: This query is very ilogical. If `cbe_user_birthday` is an `users` field that `WHERE` is always `true`. But if that is a parameter, then you need to say what table field you want compare with that range.

Comment: I added the error message to your question, which you would get for the invalid SQL you have. It helps readers a lot when you add this kind of information in questions you post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) and some [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). For instance, if the user's birthday is on `2001-01-01`, you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE cbe_user_birthday BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB('2001-01-01', INTERVAL 10 YEAR) AND
    DATE_ADD('2001-01-01', INTERVAL 10 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`BETWEEN` ...  `AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE cbe_user_birthday BETWEEN 
      cbe_user_birthday- INTERVAL 10 YEAR AND   
      cbe_user_birthday + INTERVAL 10 YEAR
```

Comment: This query is very ilogical. If `cbe_user_birthday` is an `users` field that `WHERE` is always `true`

Comment: I am just wondering what's the purpose of using such query? Isn't it equivalent to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE TRUE` ?